# Querying a table with columns with different timestamps

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1

I have a table called pmoy.data5min2010 and columns det_id, time_stamp, speed, volume. I need to query a table including columns: det_id, speed 8am, speed at 12pm and speed at 5pm, all on Aug. 11, 2010. Order table by detector id, ascendingly.

What I have so far is:

```
select det_id, speed as t1_speed, speed as t2_speed, speed as t3_speed
From pmoy.data5min2010 where t1_speed =  time_stamp '2010-08-11 08:00:00-4'
```

This gave me det_id column, 3 speed columns but they all have the same value in t1, t2, t3 speeds. How do I make column t1 - 8am data, t2 - 12pm data, and t3 - 7pm data?

my teacher said to use left join but I have no idea how to do that.

Sample data

```
det_id; time_stamp              ; speed  ; volume
311903; "2010-08-11 05:00:00-04"; 63.7885; 899
311903; "2010-08-11 05:05:00-04"; 63.8465; 859
311903; "2010-08-11 05:10:00-04"; 60.9926; 1007
311903; "2010-08-11 05:15:00-04"; 63.37;   1205
311903; "2010-08-11 05:20:00-04"; 61.5896; 1119
```

Comment: You have to operate on more than one table in order to perform JOIN.

Comment: @wojciechz No you don't, you can do multiple sub-queries on the same table and then join them together.

Comment: Can we get some sample data to work with?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Actually, please *don't* use the homework tag. Its going away and you're making work for us. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/trogdor-ate-my-homework-tag